# Placing bitmap images with String data in custom List Adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have an app that retrieve user information with images urls from the server(currently localhost).
I am able to get all the info and place the String data in HashMap and the url images I retrieved and decoded into bitmap array.

My issue is that I am having difficulties placing both into my Custom ListAdapter.
My app was working fine before i started adding the images and I am not sure if I am doing this the right way.

The first class is where the LIST ACTIVITY is and where I retrive the initial information from the server.

ANY HELP WILL BE APPRICIATED

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

 // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;


  // Creating JSON Parser object
  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


  //Arrays to hold String Data and Bitmap Data for the custom list adapter
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> listingImages;

 // url to get all products list
 private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/loginform   
         /get_all_products.php";

 // JSON Node names
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 private static final String TAG_MENU_LISTING = "menu_listing";
 private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
 private static final String TAG_RATING = "rating";
 private static final String TAG_RESTAURANT = "restaurant";
 private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
 private static final String TAG_IMAGE_PATH = "image_path";
 // products JSONArray
 JSONArray m_listing = null;
 ArrayList<String> imageArray = new ArrayList<String>();

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_items);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();




    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on selecting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String product_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            String pName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ProductReviews.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PRODUCT_ID, product_id );
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, pName);
            in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

 }

 // Response from Product Activity
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

 }

 /**
  * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
   * */
 class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                m_listing = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MENU_LISTING);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < m_listing.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = m_listing.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    //String product_id = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String image_path ="http://10.0.2.2/images/" + 
         c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_PATH);
                    //String restaurant = c.getString(TAG_RESTAURANT);

                    imageArray.add(image_path);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //map.put(TAG_PRODUCT_ID, product_id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    //map.put(TAG_IMAGE_PATH, image_path);
                    //map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);



                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);

                    System.out.println(map.get(TAG_NAME));


                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                //System.out.println(imageArray);

            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        jParser.convertInputStream(imageArray);

        return null;
    }



    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        //pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                // This R.layout.List_item is the list view layout, It can be 

     designed according to my specs
                 ListAdapter adapter = new CustomListingListAdapter(
                         AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                         R.layout.list_item_layout, new String[] { TAG_NAME 
                                });


                 setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        });

    }

 }

 public ArrayList<String> getArray(){
    System.out.println(imageArray);
    return imageArray;
 }
```

}

This is the class where I get images from URL (WORKING FINE, ABLE TO RETRIEVE URLS INTO BITMAP ARRAY )

```
public HashMap<String, Bitmap> convertInputStream(ArrayList<String> imageArray){

    for(int i = 0; i<imageArray.size(); i++){
        String url = imageArray.get(i);


        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
            final int statusCode = 
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                        + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                inputStream = null;
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


                bitmapArray.put("listing_images", bitmap);
            }
                if(inputStream != null){
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            httpGet.abort();
             Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + 
 url);
        }finally{
            if(client != null){
                client.close();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(bitmapArray);



}
    return null;

}
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> getBitmapArray(){
    listingImages.add(bitmapArray);
    System.out.println(listingImages);
    return listingImages;
}
}
```

This is my Custom List Adapter

```
 public class CustomListingListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {


    JSONParser bitarray = new JSONParser();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> bitmapArray = 
bitarray.getBitmapArray();

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int viewId;
    private String[] tag;

    //private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
    //private static final String TAG_RATING = "rating";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    //private static final String TAG_RANK = "rank";

    public CustomListingListAdapter(Context c,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data,
            int viewId, String[] tag) {
        super( c, viewId, data);

        this.context = c;
        this.data= data;
        this.viewId = viewId ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        Holder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            // Inflate the view since it does not exist
            if (vi == null) {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);

            }

            holder = new Holder();

            holder.Name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            //holder.imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


            vi.setTag(holder);  
        }else {
            holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> currentData = new HashMap<String, 
String>();
        currentData = (HashMap<String, String>) data.get(position);

        HashMap<String, Bitmap> currentImages = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
        currentImages = bitmapArray.get(position);



        if (currentData != null) {

            holder.Name.setText(currentData.get(TAG_NAME));
        }   
            if (holder.imageView != null) {

holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(currentImages.get("listing_images"));
            }

        return vi;


    }
    private static class Holder {

        public ImageView imageView;

        public TextView Name;


    }


}
```

The Error I am getting is :

```
  08-17 14:50:04.649: I/System.out(840): 
  {listing_images=android.graphics.Bitmap@40ded1a8}
            08-17 14:50:24.379: I/System.out(840): 
  {listing_images=android.graphics.Bitmap@40dead80}
            08-17 14:50:24.629: I/System.out(840):
   {listing_images=android.graphics.Bitmap@40d0fe10}


            08-17 14:50:24.629: D/AndroidRuntime(840): Shutting down VM
            08-17 14:50:24.629: W/dalvikvm(840): threadid=1: thread
   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840): FATAL 
  EXCEPTION: main
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840): 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.example.login.JSONParser.getBitmapArray(JSONParser.java:160)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.example.login.CustomListingListAdapter.<init>(CustomListingListAdapter.java:26)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.example.login.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts$1.run(AllProductsActivity.java:239)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4644)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.example.login.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:233)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.example.login.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            08-17 14:50:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            08-17 14:55:24.799: I/Process(840): Sending signal. PID: 840 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to define abstraction that describes one item of your list. The item can hold image, text and etc.

Once `convertView != null` on onGetView, never call `new` it will generate a lot of objes on scrolling of the list that will trigger GC to work and make your UI freez for some ms.